# How to add a column in a line in Ansible Jinja2 template using for loop?

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I want to update a line in Jinja2 template as follows

Let's say, I have a variable x equal to 4, then, I want a row/line as:

```
abc 1 2 3
```

in my template:

```
 {% for val in range(1, x | int) %}
      abc {{ val }} {{ val+1 }} .......
    {% endfor %}
```

If I use for loop it adds a new line, Is their way I can achieve aforementioned requirement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you are:

```
abc{% for val in range(1, x|int) %} {{ val }}{% endfor %}
```

Jinja2 is a templating engine. If you put a newline character in the source template, it will be present in the output.

You can either write everything in one line, or use [whitespace control](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/#whitespace-control) to remove unnecessary space.